# Does it make sense to use React Router with electron?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, electron

I am wondering whether this actually makes sense, or whether React Router is only for the web? Can somebody explain to me what the differences would be in using it in a electron project, and why or why not that makes sense?

Comment: I would say that you usually wouldn't use it in electron projects, because in those kinds of apps you don't have UI access to the location and history. If you want to share code between a browser and electron though I could see this it make sense. You might have to use hash based routes there, I didn't really try it.

Comment: @kraf I think you should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: OK, I'll write it up.

Comment: I'm actually getting more unsure about the answer the more I think about the question. Depending on the application it might be nice to be able to link to specific views with just an URL. It really depends on the way the application is structured in general and what kind of state management is used.